# Navigating pages in 10k post feedback clears date range filter

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, post-feedback

> **Note**: post feedback page [has been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209787/152859) and will no longer be available

Under post feedback (anonymous and low rep post feedback. last of the links on the tools page), the filters (underrated, overrated, most helpful, least helpful) and the date range (day, week, month, year, all) are not sticky when going from page to page.

To reproduce, go to the tools/post-feedback

- Click on a filter (I clicked on underrated on P.SE).
- View at this point:

[image]

- Select a range that has at least one page of results

[image]

- Scroll to the bottom of the page and go to the next page

[image]

- Take note of where you are now...
  [image]
  [image]
- You have now lost the date range filter.  Clicking on that date range filter again resets back to page 1.
- Manually adding `&page=2` to the url string does take you to page two.

[image]
[image]

Comment: reproduced, looking into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed, should be working as soon as the release 2013.7.19.862 rolls out to the sites.